# InfoPath conditional rules

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

Is there a way in InfoPath 2010 to require certain fields based on the action performed? I have a request approval view which essentially just contains all of the content of the original request form in read-only format, and the reviewer can approve the request, reject the request with feedback, or request ad-hoc review. If the reviewer chooses the 'reject' action, they should be required to provide feedback (but *only* if they choose this option). If the reviewer chooses to request an ad-hoc review, they should be required to choose a person from some sort of person picker.

TL;DR - I need to require certain fields based on the action the user chooses.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom button to submit the form and run set of rules when the button is clicked, i.e. a validate rule and a submit rule. Set the validate rule to run if Field1 is "foo" and Field2 is empty. The action is to set a trigger field that shows/hides a section with an error message. Stop rule execution after the validate rule, so the form won't be submitted.